# Division of Solid Angle When Subdividing Spherical Triangle

Tags: triangles, spherical-trigonometry, solid-angle

Suppose I have a spherical triangle (no special properties; in particular, not equilateral) with a known solid angle.  Now, I divide it into four new spherical triangles by bisecting each edge:

[image: spherical triangle: image modified by me from Wikimedia.]

Appallingly, the solid angle of the new triangles is NOT simply 1/4 that of the original triangle.  My question: **is there a way to determine how the solid angle is allocated?**

Specifically, I could recompute the solid angle (compute edge angles, then vertex angles, then spherical excess, then surface area, then steradians) at a terrible cost in trigonometry, but I'm wondering if knowing the original solid angle and the geometry of bisection makes the problem more tractable.